# Cannot put horizontal scrollbar in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have already tried to wrap the gridview around

```
 <div style="overflow-x:auto;width:800px"></div>
```

but it just doesn't work.

Whatever I do I end up getting this. 
[image]
scrollbar is there **but my gridview's column widths are not increasing** according to width. Like notes section should be bigger.

I am binding the gridview in code behind.
This is my aspx code:

```
<fieldset id="fs1" class="labels" runat="server" style="border: solid; border-width: thin; width: 98%; height: auto; border-color: #a8a8a8;">
        <div style="overflow-x: auto; width: 1100px">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%"
                CssClass="Grid" Style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Calibri;"
                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                OnPreRender="gvReport_PreRender"
                OnPageIndexChanging="gvReport_PageIndexChanging"
                PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr">
            </asp:GridView>
 </div>
<div id="div13" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
            <asp:Table runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button CssClass="buttons___" Width="160" ID="btnXcel" Text="Download Excel" OnClick="btnXcel_Click" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Button CssClass="buttons___" Width="160" ID="btnCSV" Text="Download CSV" OnClick="btnCSV_Click" runat="server" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute `style="overflow-x:scroll"` to gridview and give it width.